# Using JSF navigation cases with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, navigation

I have a couple of places in my JSF project where I'm using javscript to either open a new window or navigate the user somewhere else. Unfortunately this means that I'm writing out hard coded URLs. I already know that I can resolve el expressions within my javascript on the page, but is there a way (or an EL expression) to resolve a JSF navigation case. Alternatively, is there a way within a bean that will resolve the navigation case into a url string that I can then access from an EL expression?

Comment: Are you really using old fashioned navigation cases as in `<navigation-case>` in `faces-config.xml`, or are you using new JSF2 implicit navigation? The answer depends on that. One way is easily possible, but other isn't (at least not without hacking/writing a lot of code).

Comment: I'm using old style navigation-cases. Hopefully that the easy one.

Comment: Sorry, it's not. Here's your starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html